# .NET Core 2.2 - Unable to get app configuration from Azure AppConfig

Tags: c#, azure, app-config, app-startup, azure-app-configuration

I've created an Azure AppConfiguration store and get the Access Keys (EndPoint, Id, Secret, ConnectionString).

Now from my .NET Core WebAPI app, I want to read the configurations from Azure. I have tried many approaches that I found online but none of them works.

I already added references to the required Nuget libraries.
My `appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "ConnectionString:AppConfig": "Endpoint=https://somewhere.azconfig.io;Id=Hidden;Secret=Hidden",
    "EndPoint": "https://somewhere.azconfig.io"
}
```

In my `Program.cs` I have:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        var settings = config.Build();

        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
        {
            options.Connect(settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"]);
        });
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Then in my `Startup.cs` constructor:

```
public Startup(
    IConfiguration configuration, ---> checked this but no Azure config data
    IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv
)
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        //this.Config = configuration;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(hostingEnv.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile(...)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

And this is where I read the configurations, but all the values are `null`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var dbConnection = Configuration.GetSection("MyApp:Key1:Key2").Value; ---> get null
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnection));

        _jwtLifespan = Configuration.GetValue<int>("MyApp:Key3"); ----> get null
        _jwtSecretKey = Configuration.GetSection("MyApp:Key4").Value; ----> get null

        .....
    }
```

Anyone please check what I'm missing here and suggest me a working solution. Many thanks!

Comment: can you post appsettings.json

Comment: my appsettings.json only contains info to establish connection to Azure, where I actually get the real configuration data

Comment: https://github.com/stockampj/stylist-2.0/blob/0e8c616984e413b8bb11662809e11a767327e97d/HairSalon/Startup.cs

Comment: @LK Phuc Nguyen, any update? Could you access Azure AppConfig now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose it's your connection setting problem. From your code you are using `settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"]` to get the connection string ,however your are using `appsettings.json`.

From the tutorial: [Connect to an app configuration store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-aspnet-core-app#connect-to-an-app-configuration-store), if you want to use `settings["ConnectionStrings:AppConfig"]`, use `dotnet user-secrets set ConnectionStrings:AppConfig <your_connection_string>` to add your connection string to Secret Manager.

**Note:** Secret manager is only for local test, When the app is deployed to Azure App Service, use an application setting Connection Strings in App Service.

And if you want to use `appsettings.json`, you could try  the below code.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()

            .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)

            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var Configuration = builder.Build();
        var settings = config.Build();
        config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:AppConfig").Value);
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

And then I use the tutorial example to show the value in the AppConfiguration.

[image]

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hi George, Thanks for your help! In my `Startup.cs`, I change the way I access `config` values with the key reference directly like your suggestion and it works.